# java generate class file at runtime

Tags: java

I need to generate class at runtime, each class is mapped to a database table. Such class is model class used in ORM.

When client  specify a database table to work with,  my application check for existence of corresponding model class , if it does not exist, **generate it** and **load it** for use and **save it**, so next time we don't need to generate this class again

my question is:

1. Is that possible?
2. What open source library to use for generating class at runtime ?

some example code that illustrating how to generate simple POJO class is welcome!

best regards!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. And you don't need an external lib. The JDK provides everything you need:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, null, fileToCompile);
if (compilationResult == 0) {
    System.out.println("Compilation is successful");
} else {
    System.out.println("Compilation Failed");
}
```

Check out the [JavaCompiler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) docs.

Comment: thanks. this is a considerable approach! but generating source code is also hard for me.

Comment: @CaiNiaoCoder, can you explain in detail from what input you want to generate source code of class?